# How do you plot points in a linear array?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot  Lst := {1,2,3,3,3,4,4,6,7,7,7} in such a way that the height of the element "3" is three times the height of element "2" (or "1") and height of element "4" is twice height of element "6" (same as "1", "2"). Also "5" is purposely missing.

Comment: Not necessarily ordered so that Lst := { 3,3,3,1,2,4,4,6,7,7,7} ought to look exactly the same as the one above ...

Comment: I don't want a histogram.

Comment: `ListPlot[Tally@Lst, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledSquare], 24}]`?

Comment: also `BubbleChart[Append[1] /@ Tally@Lst, BubbleSizes -> {.1, .1}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, Automatic}}]`?

Comment: This works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### ListPlot

```
ListPlot[Counts[Lst], BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10]]
```

[image]

#### Histogram

```
Histogram[Lst, {1}, ChartElementFunction -> "Point", 
 BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10], ChartStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

#### BarChart

```
BarChart[Join[AssociationThread[Range @@ MinMax@Keys@# -> Missing[]], #] & @ Counts[Lst],
 ChartLabels -> Automatic, ChartElementFunction -> "Point",
 BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10]]
```

[image]

#### BubbleChart

```
BubbleChart[KeyValueMap[{#, #2, 1} &]@Counts[Lst], 
 BubbleSizes -> {.05, .05}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, All}}]
```

[image]